# C++ sleep() breaks program

Tags: c++, sockets, connection, sleep

I am trying to connect to a computer through a socket in c++. Basically what this code should do is try to connect, and if it cant connect, it should wait 3 seconds and try again.

```
while (true) {
    if (connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &echoserver, sizeof(echoserver)) >= 0)
    {
        break;
    }
    cout << "Connection failed!";
    sleep(3);
}
```

What the code does when its running is it will connect if it can, but if it can't, the `cout` never gets called and `sleep` never gets called either. When `sleep` is not there, the program works and continually tries to connect to the socket but there is no delay so it wouldn't connect anyway. I really need the delay to work.

Could anyone please help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once the `connect` fails, the socket refers to the failed connection. You can no longer use it to connect to anything. You need to `close` the existing socket and allocate a new one. This would have been much easier to diagnose if you had reported the error in the `cout` statement. (See docs for `strerror` and `errno`.)

Comment: Thanks I would accept this as my answer if i could but I still have to wait 7 min but thanks